# Purview API - How to get names from IDs?

Tags: azure, azure-purview

I'm trying to get the name / email of a user that is a owner / expert of an entity in Purview. Is there an API endpoint that I can use for this? The current output i get is:

```
"contacts": {"Owner": [{"id": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"}], "Expert": [{"id": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. Please use the below command and result includes Owner/Expert details.

```
GET {Endpoint}/catalog/api/atlas/v2/entity/guid/{guid}?minExtInfo={minExtInfo}&ignoreRelationships={ignoreRelationships}
```

Comment: I do apologize for introduce the spelling error when when editing your answer. Thanks for correcting that.

Comment: Setting both parameters to true does not change anything to me. I still get only the Owners and Experts IDs

Comment: `minExtInfo` is about 'whether to return minimal information for referred entities.' and `ignoreRelationships` is about 'whether to ignore relationship attributes'. Neither helper this use case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/get-by-guid?tabs=HTTP